# Embedded Google Drive forms sent blank data

Tags: html, google-docs

I want to styling embedded Google Drive form. So I create form at Google Drive, run it and copy source code from `<form> to </form>`. All looks good but when I select form values and click on submit button data sended to Google Drive spreadsheet are blank. If I use iframe that Google recommend all sended data is not blank. What I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're viewing the source code from google drive, and copying that into an I-Frame on your own webpage. This won't work since that source code is offline, reserved for sending and receiving data from google only.

I recommend creating your own excel-like spreadsheet in your I-Frame. You may be able to use the same submit button if you configure it to send to your server.

Comment: It looks like my problem come with charset where my pages has windows-1251 codepage and Google Drive data using utf-8 charset. When I changed charset this problem is gone, but now I need to re-save a lot of files from windows-1251 to utf-8 :(